# Is cosmos index used when filtering on nested list through join?

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Given that I have a NoSQL Cosmos DB container with items of the following shape:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "SmithFamily",
        "memberCount": 3,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Foo",
            "pets": [{ "name": "Bar" }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "DoeFamily",
        "memberCount": 2,
        "children": [{
            "name": "Baz",
            "pets": [{ "name": "Qux" }]
        }]
    }
]
```

and an indexing policy like:

```json
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/children/[]/pets/[]/name/?"
        },
        {
            "path": "/children/[]/name/?"
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have found that I can find the family with a pet name "Qux" by querying like so:

```sql
SELECT f
FROM family f
JOIN child IN f.children
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(child.pets, {name: "Qux"})
```

But will this query use the index I've intended for it to use, i.e. `/children/[]/pets/[]/name/?` or not? None of the examples or the descriptions in the [index-policy docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy) speaks of joins. But from what I understand from the index policy with a nested list seems to be allowed, and I get no complaints when I apply the policy.

I'm think this would be important to know especially if I want to create a composite index, for example:

```json
"compositeIndexes": [  
    [  
        {  
            "path": "/children/[]/pets/[]/name/?",
            "order":"ascending"
        },
        {  
            "path":"/memberCount",
            "order":"ascending"
        }
    ]
]
```

In order to be able to use that index, I believe I need to make sure to first filter by pet name and then order by member count so if I'd run:

```sql
SELECT f
FROM family f
JOIN child IN f.children
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(child.pets, {name: "Qux"})
ORDER BY f.memberCount
```

And it doesn't use the first path in the composite index, from what I understand, the index won't be used at all and I'd loose performance (and it would use more RU).

This all seems more straight forward on the index `/children/[]/name/?` which, unless I've misunderstood something, should be used if I query like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.children, {name: "Baz"}, true)
```

Is there a way to verify that my index is used in a specific query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference for this sort of question is just to try it.

It is easy to bulk load hundreds of thousands of documents into a collection using [the code here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/tutorial-dotnet-bulk-import).

I have done so for your Family model (250,000 documents) and applied your indexing policy.

Running

```
SELECT f
FROM family f
JOIN child IN f.children
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(child.pets, {name: "Qux"})
```

Using the "New SQL Query" tab in the portal returns the following query stats (showing the index was used)

| Metric | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Request Charge | **2.83 RUs** |
| Showing Results | 1-1 |
| Retrieved document count | 1 |
| Retrieved document size | 298 bytes |
| Output document count | 1 |
| Output document size | 353 bytes |
| **Index hit document count** | **1** |
| Index lookup time | 0.1 ms |
| Document load time | 0.02 ms |
| Query engine execution time | 0.01 ms |
| System function execution time | 0 ms |
| User defined function execution time | 0 ms |
| Document write time | 0 ms |